# Zend Framework JSON request url

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

I am new with ZF1. I am trying to get JSON response for a particular id. I can get all values from table using following code. How can I pass some parameter from url?

```
public  function emailAction(){

    $emailModel = new test_Model_DbTable_Email();
    $results = $emailModel->getEmails(518); // <-- I want here parameter from url
    $this->_helper->json($results);
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(200);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your url should be like :

```
http://yourdomain.com/index/email/id/14
```

And u can acces like in action

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
```

you can pass multi paramater :

```
http://yourdomain.com/index/email/id/14/name/john/surname/doe 

$this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
$this->getRequest()->getParam("name");
$this->getRequest()->getParam("surname");
```

your code is as follows :

```
public  function emailAction(){

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");

    $emailModel = new test_Model_DbTable_Email();
    $results = $emailModel->getEmails($id); // <-- you want to here parameter from url
    $this->_helper->json($results);
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(200);
```

}